# Java SQL database search WHERE result CONTAINS(String)

Tags: java, mysql

I am attempting to implement a search function, that searches the database for what the user has entered. I have implemented this, but it will only return the results that match exactly with what the user enters. I have tried using 'LIKE' in the SQL but this doesn't help.

Heres the SQL I am using, as the Java is not a problem.

```
Connection con = getConnection();
PreparedStatement search = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE employee_name ='"+employee+"'");
ResultSet rst = search.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must insist that you use parametrized queries since they are less prone to sql attacks.

Try something like this:

```
"SELECT * from ingredient WHERE ingredient_name LIKE'%"+ingredient+"%'");
```

Comment: perfect thank you! I found a similar thing online, but I could get the " and ' in the right places for the %.

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with this issue as well and I found a solution for it.

```java
Connection con = getConnection();
PreparedStatement search = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE employee_name = ?");
search.setString(1, employee + "%");
ResultSet rst = search.executeQuery();
```

Using concatenation in the setString function will be read in the PreparedStatement when the query is run